# Path of a curve

Tags: calculus, geometry

Consider $\textbf{R}^3$ as a manifold with the flat Euclidean metric, and coordinates $(x,y,z)$. Introduce spherical polar coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$ related to $(x,y,z)$ by

$x = r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$

$y=r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$

$z=r\cos(\theta)$

so that the metric takes the form

$ds^2=dr^2 + r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2$.

a) A particle moves along a parametrized curve given by

$x=\cos(\lambda), y=\sin(\lambda), z=\lambda$.

Express the path of the curve in the $(r,\theta,\phi)$ system.

So, that is the question. Using the metric of spherical coordinates I found this integral for the path, but I don't know how to do it and I don't know if it is right (please, someone give me a light):

$$\int\left(\sin^2(\lambda)+r^2\cos^2(\lambda)+r^2\sin^2(\theta)\right)^{1/2}d\lambda$$

Comment: Part a) isn't asking about length of the curve at all.  It's asking for you to express the $r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$ coordinates of a point on the curve.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang oh, so the integral I found is the lenght, right?

Comment: @HenriqueYukio: your integral is incorrect because $\theta$ should not appear.

Answer (score 1):

By identification,

$$\phi=\lambda$$
and
$$r\sin\theta=1,r\cos\theta=\lambda$$ so that

$$r=\sqrt{\lambda^2+1}$$ and $$\tan\theta=\lambda.$$